# Magento 1.9 custom module for managing admin users in different role

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, admin-controller, edit

Am working on a custom module for managing admin users in a custom role. Just finished the grid section. I need to edit the listed users, also a add form.

I just tried by overriding the

> 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php'

but getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp56\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Permissions\UserController.php
>   on line 94

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says that the object on which you call `setData` does not exist (most likely there is a function returning that variable and the return value is false). Whithout sharing the complete controller code it will be difficult to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I upgraded from Magento 1.10.0.2 to Magento 1.14.4.1

I had override admin.xml (app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\admin.xml) file.

In the override file after adding following code the issue was fixed.

```
<!-- admin acl users edit page -->
<adminhtml_permissions_user_edit>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/permissions_user_edit_tabs" name="adminhtml.permissions.user.edit.tabs"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/permissions_user_edit" name="adminhtml.permissions.user.edit"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="adminhtml.permissions.user.roles.grid.js" template="permissions/user_roles_grid_js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_permissions_user_edit>
<!-- admin permissions block edit page -->
<adminhtml_permissions_block_edit>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/permissions_block_edit" name="adminhtml.permissions.block.edit"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_permissions_block_edit>
<!-- admin permissions variable edit page -->
<adminhtml_permissions_variable_edit>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/permissions_variable_edit" name="adminhtml.permissions.variable.edit"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_permissions_variable_edit>
```